# NSInvalidArgumentException for implementing UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I am writing an app for iPad. I have several views. On navigation bar I have 2 buttons for shopping cart and youtube. pressing them takes to the browser in the app itself. I have made another class for browser and added an outlet for UIWebView. In browser class viewDidLoad method I wrote the following lines.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
self.title = @"Browser";

[webView loadRequest:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://cfsmail.com"]];

}
```

The build is successful and app runs. But when I press any of those buttons it terminates with following error.

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSURL URL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b39600'

Please guide

Regards
Prateek

Comment: Can you post the code that executes when the buttons are pressed?

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing wrong is that loadRequest requires a NSURLRequest, not NSURL.  Try:

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://cfsmail.com"]]];
```

Comment: Hey thanks. it worked.. I have two buttons, pressing both buttons, it opens the same link. Now i want to add one more link to the other button so that both the buttons open different links. How can I do that. is making a global string a good idea? How should I do that?

Comment: If they are two static URLs, then just define them as being static or const.  Or: `[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:linkBool ? @"http://link1.cfsmail.com" : @"http://link2.cfsmail.com"]]];`  Clean it up by using #define for the strings.